# Vectorize iteration over two large numpy arrays in parallel

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two large arrays of type `numpy.core.memmap.memmap`, called `data` and `new_data`, with > 7 million float32 items.

I need to iterate over them both within the same loop which I'm currently doing like this.

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
  if new_data[i] == 0: continue
  combo = ( data[i], new_data[i] )
  if not combo in new_values_map: new_values_map[combo] = available_values.pop()
  data[i] = new_values_map[combo]
```

However this is unreasonably slow, so I gather that using numpy's vectorising functions are the way to go.

Is it possible to vectorize with the index – so that the vectorised array can compare it's items to the corresponding item in the other array?

I thought of zipping the two arrays but I guess this would cause unreasonable overhead to prepare?

Is there some other way to optimise this operation?

For context: the goal is to effectively merge the two arrays such that each unique combination of corresponding values between the two arrays is represented by a different value in the resulting array, except zeros in the new_data array which are ignored. The arrays represent 3D bitmap images.

EDIT: `available_values` is a set of values that have not yet been used in `data` and persists across calls to this loop. `new_values_map` on the other hand is reset to an empty dictionary before each time this loop is used.

EDIT2: the data array only contains whole numbers, that is: it's initialised as zeros then with each usage of this loop with a different `new_data` it is populated with more values drawn from `available_values` which is initially a range of integers. `new_data` could theoretically be anything.

Comment: I know it is not what you are asking for, but you should use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: thanks, I'm a new to python so that's good to know.

Comment: Can you show some example of the values in data, new_data and available_values? Because float values are not accurate, it may better convert the data to integer first.

Comment: I think the problem that we're all having is that it is the mapping from `available_values` to `data` that is your core vectorization problem. As you've written it, you seem to sequentially go through each value, popping one off at a time, and assigning it to data. If this is what you're doing, you can do something like my answer. If you're doing something more complicated then we need to know about it to offer any sensible assistance.

Comment: Does it help to know that values are only drawn from the set `available_values` a tiny fraction of the time? For 99% of iterations the combo will already be in the `new_values_map` dictionary and so `available_values` is not invoked.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to use a different data structure then. You can't really avoid the loop if you're using a dictionary. The solution depends on things like how many different values there are of `combo`; can it fit in a 2D array?

Comment: What's wrong with using a dictionary? What would be a better way to make sure that for the duration of this loop each unique combination of corresponding values in `data` and `new_data` results in a consistent integer value at that index of `data`? (ideally drawing values in order from the pool of `available_values` which is maintained globally)

Answer (score 2):

In answer to you question about vectorising, the answer is probably yes, though you need to clarify what `available_values` contains and how it's used, as that is the core of the vectorisation.

Your solution will probably look something like this...

```
indices = new_data != 0

data[indices] = available_values
```

In this case, if `available_values` can be considered as a set of values in which we allocate the first value to the first value in `data` in which new_data is not 0, that should work, as long as `available_values` is a numpy array.

Let's say `new_data` and `data` take values 0-255, then you can construct an `available_values` array with unique entries for every possible pair of values in new_data and data like the following:

```
available_data = numpy.array(xrange(0, 255*255)).reshape((255, 255))
indices = new_data != 0
data[indices] = available_data[data[indices], new_data[indices]]
```

Obviously, `available_data` can be whatever mapping you want. The above should be very quick whatever is in `available_data` (especially if you only construct `available_data` once).

Answer (score 0):

Python gives you a powerful tools for handling large arrays of data: [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and [iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

Basically, they will allow to acces your data as they were regular lists, without fetching them at once to memory, but accessing piece by piece.

In case of accessing two large arrays at once, you can

```
for item_a, item_b in izip(data, new_data):
   #... do you stuff here
```

[izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) creates an iterator what iterates over the elements of your arrays at once, but it does picks pieces as you need them, not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that replacing the first two lines of loop to produce:

```
for i in numpy.where(new_data != 0)[0]:
  combo = ( data[i], new_data[i] )
  if not combo in new_values_map: new_values_map[combo] = available_values.pop()
  data[i] = new_values_map[combo]
```

has the desired effect.

So most of the time in the loop was spent skipping the entire loop upon encountering a zero in `new_data`. Don't really understand why these many null iterations were so expensive, maybe one day I will...

Comment: It's still the wrong way to do it. If you're using a numpy array, you want to get down to zero loops if you can.